# Use VBA split text string into equal substrings ensuring no word is broken

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 420 word string that I need to break into 42 characters in each cell.
[So in this case 10 cells]
But if the substring is breaking a word, the word should be overflowed into the next substring.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what you're up to. If you have a question at any point, feel free to ask once you've posted your attempted code first of course.

Comment: Use the Split Function: split("Text String to Split"," ") to get words, then check the len of adjacent words and concatenate if Len(a) + len(B) <=10

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare bones VBA script that will do this.

```
Sub breakUpSentence()
    Dim strSentenceIn As String
    Dim strSentenceOut As String
    Dim arrWords As Variant
    Dim strWord As Variant
    Dim cellWrite As Range

    'get the sentence
    strSentenceIn = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    'break it up into words storing the words in an array
    arrWords = Split(strSentenceIn, " ")

    'Set the first cell to write out to
    Set cellWrite = Sheet1.Range("B1")

    'Iterate through words
    For Each strWord In arrWords

        'Add the word to the output sentence, only include a space if the sentence is already populated
        If strSentenceOut = "" Then strSentenceOut = strWord Else strSentenceOut = strSentenceOut & " " & strWord

        'If the output sentence is now greater than or equal to 42 characters, then write it out
        If Len(strSentenceOut) >= 42 Then

            'Write it out
            cellWrite.Value = strSentenceOut

            'Increment to the next cell we want to write to
            Set cellWrite = cellWrite.Offset(, 1)

            'Clear the output sentence
            strSentenceOut = ""
        End If

    Next strWord

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about split the string into an array of words usind blank as a delimiter and the split function?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Then walk through the array and decide what to do based on the length of each value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

Was having some trouble, but have figured it.
[Credit to the original code]

This uses a UDF.

```
splittext(range, part number, maximum allowed number)
```

The only catch is multiple formulas need to be used to get the various parts.

```
Sub breakUpSentenceEqualParts()

Dim strSentenceIn As String
Dim strSentenceOut As String
Dim arrWords As Variant
Dim strWord As Variant
Dim cellWrite As Range

strSentenceIn = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

arrWords = Split(strSentenceIn, " ")

Set cellWrite = Sheet1.Range("B1")

For Each strWord In arrWords

        If strSentenceOut = "" Then strSentenceOut = strWord Else strSentenceOut = strSentenceOut & " " & strWord

        If Len(strSentenceOut) >= 42 Then

        cellWrite.Value = strSentenceOut

        Set cellWrite = cellWrite.Offset(, 1)

        strSentenceOut = ""
    End If

Next strWord

End Sub
```